# Z3 How to check whether a model satisfies a new assertion/constraint

Tags: z3, z3py

I am using z3py for coding. See the following example.

```py
from z3 import *

x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')

s = Solver()

s.add(x+y>3)

if s.check()==sat:
    m = s.model()
    # how to check whether model m satisfies x+y<5 ?
    print(m)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evaluate expressions in the model:

```py
from z3 import *

x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')

s = Solver()

s.add(x+y>3)

if s.check()==sat:
    m = s.model()
    print(m)
    print(m.evaluate(x+y<5))
```

This prints:

```
[x = 4, y = 0]
True
```